# Why does Android beta testing allow other users to download apk

Tags: android, beta, beta-testing

I have a Google group with specific beta testers. My app (released as beta on the developer console in Google Play) queries content from my server. Now I see that other users than from the Google group are querying the server. It's a functionality that is not available on older versions on my app.

How can that be?

Comment: Maybe some member leaked the APK? For next versions you could track the user by collecting some data of its device.

Comment: Is your Google+ Community for beta testers private? Do you see anyone in that group who are not invited?

Comment: @joaquin: I already do track the identity; that's why I found out that there are registrations not in my beta group

Comment: @DevrimTuncer: I have no Google+ community. It's a Google group where I manage the members

Comment: It sounds to me like someone's managed to extract the APK and leaked it

Comment: @joaquin, Boardy: Tow different users? I don't think so.

Comment: So you found a Google bug?

Comment: @joaquin: Maybe. The strange thing is, that the registration was made not even 10 minutes after I uploaded the apk to Google Play. I didn't inform my beta testers about the test release in this time. I don't see how they could have found out and manage to leak the apk in this under 10 minutes time span.

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with several apps in beta testing, never had this problem,

- Check if the list of users defined in your Group of testers is correct (Manage list of Testers)
- Your app must be published in "Beta Testing", with the option "Promote to Prod" pending.
  [image]

Comment: Thanks Elenasys, I did that as the first task and double checked it too, after I realized those strange registrations on my server